# Creating flat list from single float or list of floats

Tags: python

I wish to iterate over a zip of objects and floats together using a parent class function. Sometimes the subclasses have three objects and three floats in a list, this works fine:

```
L = [A,B,C]
F = [1,2,3]

for f, o in zip(L,F):
    # do stuff
```

Sometimes the subclass has one object and one float

```
L = A
F = 1

for f, o in zip(L,F):
    # TypeError
```

This throws an exception because F is not iterable.

If I try:

```
F = list(F)
```

This works for 2 or more floats but throws an exception for a single float (it's still not iterable :)).

If I try:

```
F = [F]
```

This solves the 1 float case but now returns a nested list when there are two or more floats!

```
a = [1,2]
[a] = [[1,2]]
```

Is there a simple builtin way to receive either a single float or list of floats and return a single flat list? Or do I need something like itertools.chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if you already have a list, and if not create one with a single element:

```
f = f if isinstance(f,list) else [f]
```

For example:

```
>>> f = 1
>>> f = f if isinstance(f,list) else [f]
>>> f 
[1]
>>> f = [1,2]
>>> f = f if isinstance(f,list) else [f]
>>> f
[1, 2]
```

Note, I'm assuming your using `list`s but you could use `collections.Iterable` for a more generic solution.

Further note, I don't know where `F`/`f` came from, but ideally it would have been initially created this way rather than fixing it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `a = a if isinstance(a, collections.Iterable) else [a]`. This makes sure a is either iterable or converts it to list. Also you need not convert a, you could assign the result to another variable.

Comment: you mean `[a]` not `list(a)` but yes, we had the same idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can design your objects so that they have a builtin `__iter__` method along with `__len__`:

```
class CertainObject:
     def __init__(self):
         self.variables = [23, 4, 2]
     def __len__(self):
         return len(self.variables)
     def __iter__(self):
         for i in self.variables:
             yield i
```

Case 1(Multiple objects):

```
L = [CertainObject(), CertainObject(),CertainObject()]
F = [1,2,3]

for f, o in zip(L,F):
   pass
```

Case 1 (singe object):

```
A = CertainObject()
F = 1
for a, b in zip(A, [F]*len(A)):
    print(a, b)
```

With `__iter__`, iterating over the instance of the object will not raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your case that returns a nested list, but then cast the list as a numpy array and use the flatten() function, then re-cast as a list if you want it that way.

```
a = list(np.array(a).flatten())
```

This way, a = 1 will turn into [1], a = [1, 2] will turn into [1, 2], and a = [[1, 2]] will turn into [1, 2], so all outputs are lists.

Answer (score 0):

## Use extend

```
L = []
F = []

L.extend([A])
F.extend([B])

for f,o in zip(L,F):
    # do stuff
```

This should not give you problems both with one item lists and with more than one item lists (it won't be nested).

## example 1 item:

```
L = []
F = []
A = 1
B = 1
L.extend([A])
F.extend([B])
for f,o in zip(L,F):
    print(f,o)
```

> otput

1 1

## Example more items

```
L = []
F = []
A = [1,2,3]
B = [1,2,3]
L.extend([A])
F.extend([B])
for f,o in zip(L,F):
    print(f,o)
```

> output

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```